# Structure of Cohen-Macaulay local algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I have the following question:

> Let $(A,\mathfrak m)$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local $k$-algebra, where $A/\mathfrak m=k$. Then there is a homomorphism $R=k[X_1,\cdots ,X_n]\rightarrow S$ so that $S$ is a finite flat $R$-module and $A$ is a localisation of $S$ at some suitable maximal ideal.

I can't construct $S$. Can anyone please help me how to solve this problem? Any hint is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: In general this is false. Consider $A=k[[x]]$. You will at least need to assume that $A$ is essentially finite type $k$-algebra.

Comment: @Mohan Can you elaborate why this is false, i.e, why there is no finite flat morphism from a polynomial ring over $k$ to $A$.

If we assume it is finite type then using Noether Normalisation we can have a finite morphism. But why that will be flat? Or can you show any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: In your situation, $S$ has finite transcendence degree over $k$ and thus, if true, so will $A$. But $k[[x]]$ has infinite transcendence degree over $k$.